# What was Grandpa really doing?

Tags: wordplay, no-computers

"Guess what happened during my walk". Said Grandpa

> "I saw gods in a ghetto"! He continued with a smile.
>
> "What?" I said.
>
> "Well, not really. But can you guess what I did?", Grandpa asked.
>
> "NO" I surrendered.
>
> "Here is a clue", he said. "American Dragons"

What did he do? What is this clue about?

Comment: Are we supposed to make anything of the fact that most of the conversation is in the blockquote but the first line is not, or of the oddities of punctuation and capitalization? Or are those all typos?

Comment: Not really @msh210. Just my style of writing

Comment: What does "no-computers" mean in this context?  It doesn't appear to be a calculation type problem.

Comment: The clue "American Dragons" is an anagram of "Consider Anagram".

Comment: @SteveV see kevin omar's astute comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to say Grandpa was:

> eating hot dogs

because

> "I saw gods in a ghetto" is an anagram of "I was eating hot dogs".
>
>  And the clue "American Dragons" is an anagram of "Consider Anagram" (from kevin omar in comments).

Comment: Finally!   Good Job @JS1!

Comment: Well done - I've been trying to work this one out all day after spotting the anagram clue! "I showed Sting a goat" was my favourite...